# Experiencing high latency when querying DynamoDB from an EC2 instance

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, latency

I have a basic NodeJS web application which scans a DynamoDB table with only ~10 items. When I run the application on locally on my machine, the operation takes less than 1 second.

However, when I deploy the application on an EC2 instance, the same operation takes almost 5 seconds. The EC2 instance(t2.micro) and DynamoDB table are in the same region. I have also enabled VPC Endpoint Gateway service for DynamoDB, but the latency remains the same.

Here are the curl requests to test the performance:

`curl -X POST   http://localhost:9000/login -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{ "email": "xyz@gmail.com", "password": "admin", "type": "talent" }' -s -o /dev/null -w  "%{time_starttransfer}\n"                                         0.394470`

`curl -X POST   http://EC2_IP_ADDRESS:9000/login -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{ "email": "xyz@gmail.com", "password": "admin", "type": "talent" }' -s -o /dev/null -w  "%{time_starttransfer}\n"                                         5.207561`

Please help me understand what can be causing these latencies and how do I achieve low latency while querying DynamoDB from an EC2 instance.

Comment: Update:
Earlier I was running the application in a Docker container.
I ran the application on a bare Ubuntu AMI, and the latencies dropped immediately.
So, the problem is while running the application in a container. I tried changing the base Docker image from 8 to 10, but the problem still persists. 
Please help me understand where the problem could be.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find what is the time taken by the database and the network. To do that you can check the following

1. Run your query directly on the DynamoDB to check the amount of time the database is taking. Check whether the query itself
2. Check whether the turnaround time difference for your query between code exection on EC2 server and your local machine the same with or without VPC endpoint?

Comment: Hey @Juned, thank you for your response. To answer your questions:
1. The query from the DynamoDB console is taking barely a few milliseconds
2. The VPC Endpoint doesn't make any difference

Answer (score 0):

The extended latency is very likely not due to DynamoDB if you think about the network hops

1. EC2 => EC2 => dynamodb (`curl http://localhost/...`)
2. Your desktop => internet => EC2 => dynamodb (`curl http://EC2_IP/...`)

It's possible you would experience a similar high latency if you just bypass dynamodb call e.g. comment out the code that makes a db call and return a mock response - I suspect you'll get a similar latency as #2

Comment: Hey ubi, thank you for your response. I hope you have seen the update I posted to the question. I'll post it again: 
Update: Earlier I was running the application in a Docker container. I ran the application on a bare Ubuntu AMI, and the latencies dropped immediately. So, the problem is while running the application in a container. I tried changing the base Docker image from 8 to 10, but the problem still persists. Please help me understand where the problem could be.

Comment: Interesting.. assuming container and EC2 are on the same VPC/region. Was it the first request or all requests to container takes ~5 secs?